# Vertical text alignment \node[draw,circle] at (A) {text}

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

there's a complex TikZ/PGFPlots-graphic and a simple problem, but I didn't get the solution.

[image: PNG of the minimal example]

I made an annotation to the graph and display the annotation within legend section. But the same TikZ-code looks different.

```
%The symbol in legend section
\addlegendimage{legend image code/.code={
\node[minimum size=6pt,draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,line width=0.4pt,node font=\small] at (0,0) {A};
}}
%The symbol in annotation
\node[minimum size=6pt,draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,line width=0.4pt,node font=\small] at (A) {A};
```

The size of the circle and the vertical alignment of the label is different.
[image: Comparison of both circle-nodes]

The minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newlength{\plotwidth}\setlength{\plotwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\newlength{\plotheight}\setlength{\plotheight}{0.7\plotwidth}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=1.13,
   scale only axis,
   every axis plot/.append style={line width=1pt}}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
   nomorepostactions/.code={\let\tikz@postactions=\pgfutil@empty},
   mymark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,
   mark= between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm with{
       \tikzset{#2,every mark}\tikz@options \pgfuseplotmark{#1}},},
   postaction={decorate},
   /pgfplots/legend image post style={
      mark=#1,mark options={#2},every path/.append style={nomorepostactions}},},}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
   arrowlineNeu/.style={
      decoration={
         markings,
        mark=between positions 0.15 and 0.65 step 6em with {\arrow [scale=1.5]{stealth}}
        }, postaction=decorate
},
arrowlinelegend/.style={
   decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.7 and 1 step 8em with {\arrow [scale=1.5]{stealth}}
        }, postaction=decorate
},
}
\begin{axis}[
   width=\plotwidth,
   height=\plotheight,
   axis lines=box,
   xlabel={$H$ \tikz{\draw  [-{Latex[black]},color=black, solid, line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (8mm,0mm)}},
   ylabel={$B$ \tikz{\draw  [-{Latex[black]},color=black, solid, line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (8mm,0mm)}},
   ymin=-1.3,ymax=1.3,
   xmin=-7,xmax=7,
   samples=20,
   legend pos=north west,
   legend style={cells={align=left},
         legend cell align=left}]
%Legend
\addlegendimage{arrowlinelegend, solid, black!60}
\addlegendentry{Neukurve}
\addlegendimage{legend image code/.code={\node[minimum size=6pt,draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,line width=0.4pt,node font=\small] at (0,0) {A};}}
\addlegendentry{Spontane\\Magnetisierung}
%Plot
\addplot[black!60,arrowlineNeu,domain=0:7,no marks] {tanh(x/2)+x/50};
\addplot[black!60,arrowlineNeu,domain=0:-7,no marks] {tanh(x/2)+x/50};
%Annotation
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0.5,-0.275);
\draw[black!100,solid] (axis cs:0.0,0.0) [fill=black] circle [radius=1.5pt] -- (axis cs:0.5,-0.275) coordinate (A);
\node[minimum size=6pt,draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,line width=0.4pt,node font=\small] at (A) {A};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try to add `text depth=0pt` in the option of your 2 circles. It seems to solve your issues but I don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for it in PGFPlots manual and found what's going on. The style `every axis legend` is always installed and it's default is the following:

```
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.style={
      cells={anchor=center},% Centered entries
      inner xsep=3pt,inner ysep=2pt,nodes={inner sep=2pt,text depth=0.15em},
      anchor=north east,
      shape=rectangle,
      fill=white,
      draw=black,
      at={(0.98,0.98)}
      }
}
```

So the culprit is the `text depth=0.15em`, by manually setting it to `text depth=<dim>` to both nodes you'll get the legend and annotation to be identical.

### Here's a MWE (with some changes):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newlength{\plotwidth}\setlength{\plotwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\newlength{\plotheight}\setlength{\plotheight}{0.7\plotwidth}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=1.13,
   scale only axis,
   every axis plot/.append style={line width=1pt}}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
   nomorepostactions/.code={\let\tikz@postactions=\pgfutil@empty},
   mymark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,
   mark= between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm with{
       \tikzset{#2,every mark}\tikz@options \pgfuseplotmark{#1}},},
   postaction={decorate},
   /pgfplots/legend image post style={
      mark=#1,mark options={#2},every path/.append style={nomorepostactions}},},}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
   mynode/.style={
        minimum size=6pt,
        draw,
        circle,
        fill=white,
        inner sep=0pt,
        line width=0.4pt,
        node font=\small,
        text depth=0.15em},%<<<<< text depth (I kept the PGFplots default)
   arrowlineNeu/.style={black!60,
      decoration={
         markings,
        mark=between positions 0.15 and 0.65 step 6em with {\arrow [scale=1.5]{stealth}}
        }, postaction=decorate
},
arrowlinelegend/.style={black!60,
   decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.7 and 1 step 8em with {\arrow [scale=1.5]{stealth}}
        }, postaction=decorate
},
}
\begin{axis}[
   width=\plotwidth,
   height=\plotheight,
   axis lines=box,
   xlabel={$H$ \tikz{\draw  [-{Latex[black]},color=black, solid, line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (8mm,0mm)}},
   ylabel={$B$ \tikz{\draw  [-{Latex[black]},color=black, solid, line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (8mm,0mm)}},
   ymin=-1.3,ymax=1.3,
   xmin=-7,xmax=7,
   samples=20,
   legend pos=north west,
   legend style={cells={align=left},
         legend cell align=left}]
%Legend
\addlegendimage{arrowlinelegend, solid, black!60}
\addlegendentry{Neukurve}
\addlegendimage{legend image code/.code={\node[mynode] at (0,0) {A};}}
\addlegendentry{Spontane\\Magnetisierung}
%Plot
\addplot[arrowlineNeu,domain=0:7,no marks] {tanh(x/2)+x/50};
\addplot[arrowlineNeu,domain=0:-7,no marks] {tanh(x/2)+x/50};
%Annotation
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0.5,-0.275);
\draw[black,solid,fill] (axis cs:0.0,0.0) circle [radius=1.5pt] -- (A) node[mynode] {A};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```